# How can I get data from two different sources in an Nunit test?

Tags: c#, excel, unit-testing, attributes, nunit

Currently I am using Nunit's attribute `TestCaseSource` as below which reads data from an Excel sheet, parses it and yield returns the data as `IEnumerable` to the test:

```
[Test]
[TestCaseSource(typeof(Class_Name), nameof(Method_providing_data))]
public void Test_Name(IEnumerable_type_from_method)
   {....
 ...
}
```

I want to read some more data from another Excel which is depended by this test. I tried:

```
[Test]
[TestCaseSource(typeof(Class_Name), nameof(Method_providing_data_1))]
[TestCaseSource(typeof(Class_Name), nameof(Method_providing_data_2))]

public void Test_Name(IEnumerable_type_1_from_method_1, IEnumerable_type_2_from_method_2)
    {....
...
}
```

but this throws a run-time error: *Wrong number of arguments provided*.

How can I achieve this without modifying/combining the methods that are passing the data to the test, since I don't have rights to change that part of the code?

Also, I'll be glad if someone can help me understand how the parameters of `TestCaseSource` attribute and the parameters of the test method are related?

How does the test method recognize that the parameters passed to it are coming from the `TestCaseSource` attribute?

I couldn't find this information in the `TestCaseSource` attribute [documentation](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=testCaseSource&r=2.5.9) or anywhere.

Comment: Did you try with just the second source? Perhaps it is truly delivering incorrect number of parameters?

Comment: Also, you could easily build a new method that takes data from the other two and concatenates.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Yes, I tried only with the second source and it just works fine. BTW., building a new method seems to be a good idea :) 
Yet I think Nunit should have provided the ability to work with multiple testcasesources in a single method.
I shall wait for someone (Or even you could :)) who can answer my second part of the question, about the relationship between the parameters passed to the test method and `TestCaseSource` attribute parameter

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen
Creating a new method has a problem. If I write a test method A which reads data from source A and test method B to read data from source B, each of them will run independently. How can I write test C, which can invoke both these tests before it is run? If I put both the methods test A and test B in `[Setup]` it will affect other tests in the class. Any suggestions please?

Comment: Please ask that as a new question, because that is what it is. You're now talking about inter-test dependencies, something which isn't a very good idea, but this is a new question.